# How to unpivot multiple columns in PySpark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, unpivot, cross-apply

The columns CGL, CPL, EO should become Coverage Type, the values for CGL, CPL, EO should go in column Premium, and values for CGLTria,CPLTria,EOTria should go in column Tria Premium.

```sql
declare @TestDate table  ( 
                            QuoteGUID varchar(8000), 
                            CGL money, 
                            CGLTria money, 
                            CPL money,
                            CPLTria money,
                            EO money,
                            EOTria money
                            )

INSERT INTO @TestDate (QuoteGUID, CGL, CGLTria, CPL, CPLTria, EO, EOTria)
VALUES ('2D62B895-92B7-4A76-86AF-00138C5C8540', 2000, 160, 674, 54, 341, 0),
       ('BE7F9483-174F-4238-8931-00D09F99F398', 0, 0, 3238, 259, 0, 0),
       ('BECFB9D8-D668-4C06-9971-0108A15E1EC2', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)

SELECT * FROM @TestDate
```

OUTPUT:

[image: 1]

The result should be like that:

[image: 2]

I have done it using cross apply with values in SQL, but I want to implement it using PySpark.

Answer (score 3):

Before usual unpivoting (using `stack`), you could combine groups of columns to one column using `array`.

Input:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [('2D62B895-92B7-4A76-86AF-00138C5C8540', 2000, 160, 674, 54, 341, 0),
     ('BE7F9483-174F-4238-8931-00D09F99F398', 0, 0, 3238, 259, 0, 0),
     ('BECFB9D8-D668-4C06-9971-0108A15E1EC2', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)],
    ['QuoteGUID', 'CGL', 'CGLTria', 'CPL', 'CPLTria', 'EO', 'EOTria']
)
```

Script:

```py
df2 = df.select(
    'QuoteGUID',
    F.expr("stack(3, 'CGL', array(CGL, CGLTria), 'CPL', array(CPL, CPLTria), 'EO', array(EO, EOTria)) as (CoverageType, _P)")
)
df3 = df2.select(
    'QuoteGUID',
    'CoverageType',
    F.col('_P')[0].alias('Premium'),
    F.col('_P')[1].alias('TriaPremium'),
)
```

Result:

```py
df3.show(truncate=0)
# +------------------------------------+------------+-------+-----------+
# |QuoteGUID                           |CoverageType|Premium|TriaPremium|
# +------------------------------------+------------+-------+-----------+
# |2D62B895-92B7-4A76-86AF-00138C5C8540|CGL         |2000   |160        |
# |2D62B895-92B7-4A76-86AF-00138C5C8540|CPL         |674    |54         |
# |2D62B895-92B7-4A76-86AF-00138C5C8540|EO          |341    |0          |
# |BE7F9483-174F-4238-8931-00D09F99F398|CGL         |0      |0          |
# |BE7F9483-174F-4238-8931-00D09F99F398|CPL         |3238   |259        |
# |BE7F9483-174F-4238-8931-00D09F99F398|EO          |0      |0          |
# |BECFB9D8-D668-4C06-9971-0108A15E1EC2|CGL         |0      |0          |
# |BECFB9D8-D668-4C06-9971-0108A15E1EC2|CPL         |0      |0          |
# |BECFB9D8-D668-4C06-9971-0108A15E1EC2|EO          |0      |0          |
# +------------------------------------+------------+-------+-----------+
```